# SIM cards Trace to buyer

Tags: tracking, simcard

Hi I was wondering if a SIM card can be traced to the person you purchased it. Let's say I bought a SIM card and used it to make it look like a friend was sending messages could that card be traced right back to the original buyer?

Comment: Depends who's doing the tracing,  did you give personal details or register the card? Did you pay by card in a shop with cctv? Depending on the content of your mesaages,  you may comitting an offence related to malicious communications.  And if you weren't I guess you wouldn'the be asking about a trace. This isn't the place to get help breaking the law.

Comment: No I bought it online

Comment: And it was a prank but I want to know if it could be traced. So it's registered in someone else's name but I bought it so would it come back to me